# Samba 3.6 and Samba4

Tags: networking, samba, shared-folders, active-directory, smb

I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 and samba 3.6 (the version of samba that is installed for Ubuntu 12.10, by default). Everything works fine. I can access shared folders and shared printers of Windows PCs.

I read that Samba4 provide access and login to ActiveDirectory of Windows Server (more fluent access that Samba 3.6), so I want install Samba4.

Can I replace samba3.6 with samba4? **OR** Can I install samba4 alongside samba3.6?

**Samba4 (SAMBA) is the next version of Samba 3.6 (SMB) or are differents packages and services?**

Samba4 provide all the same functionality that Samba 3.6 plus all the functionality to access and use ActiveDirectory ?  Samba3.6 provide access to ActiveDirectory?

I decided to test samba4 and I tried to remove samba 3.6. Everything was fine until I tried to remove libwclient (or libwclient0). When I mark it to be removed in Synaptic, I get a notice that is necessary to remove kde-runtime, mplayer, k3b, gecko, gnome mplayer, lubuntu-desktop, etc, etc. So I didn't remove and I reinstalled all of samba3.6

What happen if i remove samba3.6 completly (libwclient (or libwclient0) too), what happen with this software (kde-runtime, mplayer, k3b, gecko, gnome mplayer, lubuntu-desktop, etc, etc)

**Can I install samba4 and get all the same functionality that samba3.6 (access to shared folders and printers of windows) plus ActiveDirectory and reinstall all that software (kde-runtime, mplayer, k3b, gecko, gnome mplayer, lubuntu-desktop, etc, etc)  and this software will with samba4 instead of  samba3.6?**

(Sorry for my english)

Thanks, Alejandro

Answer (score 6):

At this time Samba 3 and Samba 4 are mostly complementary. Samba 3 is a mature file server, etc., and Active Directory domain *member*. Samba 4 is the first version of Samba that can act as an Active Directory domain *controller*. Just want to share files? Install Samba 3. Want to run a DC? Install Samba 4.

Ref: the recent release announcement of Samba 4.0: https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba-technical/2012-December/089397.html

Ref: https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_AD_DC_HOWTO

Comment: Samba 3 and Samba 4 codebases were amalgamated upstream some time ago. Recently the two versions have been amalgamated in Debian packages as well. In unstable there is now a single `samba` source package with version number greater than 4. Its binaries include the best of Samba 3 and Samba 4.

Comment: In the latest stable version available of ubuntu (13.10) is available this integration of samba 3 and 4?
Now I have ubuntu 12.10 but soon I'll make a disk image and will do an update from 12.10 to 13.10
 
What do you think jdthood?
Will I have problems in that upgrade from ubuntu 12.10 to 13.10? because I have some special features: partition with windows 7, disk encryption with truecrypt data (not the ubuntu disk system), some programs installed outside the ubuntu software center, etc

Comment: The amalgamated samba packages have not yet made it into Ubuntu Saucy. As for your proposed upgrade, I don't know what the connection is between that and the question asked here. I suggest you ask a question about your particular case in Ubuntu Forums.